# FBlikeControl button image and Text change

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios8

I have added FbLike button which provided in SDK 3.19.Its working fine but I need to change the image and text of button.I have googled but did not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible the same way you would change the default `FBLoginView` button.

```
loginView.frame = CGRectMake(320/2 - 93/2, self.view.frame.size.height -200, 93, 93);

for (id loginObject in loginView.subviews)
{
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
        UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_HERE"];
        loginButton.alpha = 0.7;
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [loginButton sizeToFit];
    }
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
        loginLabel.text = @"";
        loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: its not working.if condition not became true.Have you tried this.